# What might cause the Bitcoin client to take a long time to see a new, unconfirmed transaction?

Tags: transactions, network

I've noticed that sometimes, when I send Bitcoins from one client to another, the recipient client might not see the transaction, sometimes until it already has one or more confirmations. Both clients are connected to 30-40 nodes.

Comment: Only time I got that is when I was trying to experiment with double-spending against myself. Are both of your's Bitcoin clients up to date?

Comment: Both clients are up to date.

Answer (score 3):

Is one of the clients disconnected when you send payment with the other? This often happens to me when I send a transaction to the other OS on a dual-boot system, meaning the receiving client is down when the transaction is broadcast.

I'm guessing this happens because all nodes the client connects to when he comes online have already broadcast the transaction, so they won't send it again to him. He'll only get it as part of a block when it is found.

Comment: Nope. Both machines are up the whole time, and they have different IP addresses. The server is the one that takes a long time to see the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction is "spam-like" other nodes won't relay it.  This is to help protect the Bitcoin network from too many low priority transactions.

Was the transaction for a tiny amount? (e.g., under 0.01 BTC?) and no fee paid?  If so, that's kind of "spam-like".  I don't know the exact algorithm, but both of those are factors.